# Terminal window in Jupyter notebook is not getting launched

Tags: terminal, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to open terminal in Jupyter notebook, it will appear for 2 seconds and it disappears immediately. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to open terminal by the following method?

[image]

If so, try restarting jupyter. That always seems to clear any issues for me.
Else, try using the `%%bash` or `!` cell magics inside of a notebook in order to use the terminal.